# Fortan subroutine warning in Abaqus (warning LNK4210: .CRT section exists; there may be unhandled static initializers or terminators)

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran, abaqus

I am facing a problem running this specific subroutine [cdpm2vumat.f](https://github.com/seungwookseok/ABAQUS-version-CDPM2/blob/master/cdpm2vumat.f) in abaqus. The job log file shows this error.

```
cdpm2vumat.f(677): remark #8291: Recommended relationship between field width 'W' and the number of fractional digits 'D' in this edit descriptor is 'W>=D+7'.
 1        format(1x,A,1pE9.3,A,1pE9.3)
-------------------------^
cdpm2vumat.f(677): remark #8291: Recommended relationship between field width 'W' and the number of fractional digits 'D' in this edit descriptor is 'W>=D+7'.
 1        format(1x,A,1pE9.3,A,1pE9.3)
----------------------------------^
End Compiling Single Precision Abaqus/Explicit User Subroutines
Begin Linking Single Precision Abaqus/Explicit User Subroutines
   Creating library explicitU.lib and object explicitU.exp
libirc.lib(fast_mem_ops.c.obj) : warning LNK4210: .CRT section exists; there may be unhandled static initializers or terminators
End Linking Single Precision Abaqus/Explicit User Subroutines
```

I am using Abaqus 2021, VS 2019, for linking fortan I used inel one api and hpc kit. The linking is passed in abaqus verification. I tried other subroutione which are working perfectly.What does this warning mean actually? And how can I solve it?

Comment: It means that the field width (9, here) is insufficient to write a general number (which may be negative) in scientific notation. For example, -1.234e+56 requires 10 places. You can use 1pE10.3 (or, better, es10.3) as a format specifier instead. In general, you will require a field width (at least) 7 places more than the number of decimal places. For really big numbers even that might not be enough. BTW, I would use some spaces (1x) between your outputs, or they won’t be separated.

Comment: Also, I don’t think the warning in your title has anything to do with the (more prominent) one in your post. You may have some run-time issues ahead.

Comment: @lastchance Thanks. I modified it as you said, and the 'W > D+7' error is solved. However, the warning "libirc.lib(fast_mem_ops.c.obj) : warning LNK4210: .CRT section exists; there may be unhandled static initializers or terminators" still persists, and the job was aborted. Could you please suggest what I should do to solve this specific error?"

Comment: Firstly the .CRT thing is not an error, its only a warning. Secondly it may be nothing to worry about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529003/crt-section-what-does-this-warning-mean which may well be a duplicate, but as I know nothing about this I am not going to suggest it as one. Does the code run? Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by eliminating any `stop` or `error stop` statements and replacing with `call XPLB_EXIT`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).